# How do this last step in a mathematical induction is simplified? $^2(+1)^2+4(k+1)^3 -> (+1)^2(K+2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I'm working from an online problem that explain how to prove this Mathematical induction. But I just cannot follow their reasoning. Can anyone help out on the last step?

Prove that
$1^3+2^3 +3^3+· · ·+n^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

assuming it is true for $n+1$

let's prove that it is true for $n = k+1$

$(1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + · · · + k^3+ (k + 1)^3 = \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}$

Let's simplify the left hand side:

$(1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + · · · + k^3+ (k + 1)^3 = \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)^3$

= $\frac{k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3}{4}$

= $\frac{(k+1)^2[k^2+4(k+1)]}{4}$

=$\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}$

This is supposed to prove the Mathematical induction but I don't see how the right side of the nominator is simplified in this last step.

$[k^2+4(k+1)^3] -> (K+2)^2$

Can anyone help?

Comment: Multiply out $(k+2)^2$; what do you get?

Comment: The last step is not what you wrote, i.e., $[k^2+4(k+1)^3] -> (K+2)^2$, but it's $[k^2+4(k+1)] -> (K+2)^2$ instead. Is the extra exponent of $3$ just a typo or is this perhaps where your confusion comes from?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, this is where I am confused. I don't understand where is the exponent 3 goes. $k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3$ becomes $(k+1)^2(k+2)^2$

Comment: @Pre-Calculuslearner From $k^2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1)^3$, taking a common factor of $(k+1)^2$ out gives the next line, i.e., $(k + 1)^2[k^2 + 4(k + 1)]$. Then expanding the part inside the square brackets, as done in Popular Power's answer, gives that $k^2 + 4(k + 1) = k^2 + 4k + 4 = (k + 2)^2$. This means $(k + 1)^2[k^2 + 4(k + 1)] = (k + 1)^2(k+2)^2$.

Comment: Oh great! This clarify everything! I couldn't see the factorization happening, I thought the $k^2$  was moved to the right side of the parenthesis and the square bracket added only as a visual aid in preparation for the next step. I did not see the factorization happen there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$k^2+4k+4=k^2+2 \cdot k \cdot 2 + 2^2 = (k+2)^2$